# Your input ran out of data

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

```
history = model.fit_generator(
      train_generator,
      steps_per_epoch=50,  
      epochs=10,
      verbose=1,
      validation_data = validation_generator,
      validation_steps=50)
```

tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 5000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

Comment: please help me!!!

Comment: We need you to include how you construct the `train_generator`, otherwise, we cannot help. The error is telling you that you haven't generated enough batches.

Comment: train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        '/content/retinopathy/retinopathy/new_train',  # This is the source directory for training images
        target_size=(300, 300),  # All images will be resized to 150x150
        batch_size=128,
        # Since we use binary_crossentropy loss, we need binary labels
        class_mode='binary')

Comment: Looks good so far. You have a mismatch between your `target_size` param and your comment, but, obviously, that's not the problem. How many subdirectories does `/content/retinopathy/retinopathy/new_train` have? And, how many images are there in each of them?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, we need to pay attention two items:

1. How to define batch size and  batch_size and steps_per_epoch.
   The simple answer is steps_per_epoch=total_train_size//batch_size
2. How to define max number of epochs for the training process.
   This is not as straightforward as the first one.

Majority answers covered the first topic, I didn't find good answer for second, try to explain as below:

I have a train data set of 93 data samples, and batch_size of 32, so the for the first question:
steps_per_epoch=total_train_size//batch_size=93//32=2

For the second question, it will depend on how many not repeated batch your data generator can provide, if I have 93 data samples and each batch need 32 two samples so the each epoch has 2 train steps. You will have 93//2 = 46 epochs that will able to provide not repeated batches, the epoch 47 will cause this error.

I didn't find reference for tensorflow data generator so this is just my understanding, if there are anything wrong please correct me, thanks!